# Spock invocation for Groovy's generated getters using a final field

Tags: groovy, getter-setter, spock

Groovy [generates getters and setters](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Beans) for all your class' fields. So when you do this:

```
class Foo {
    final bar
}
new Foo().bar
```

you're actually calling the generated method `Foo.getBar()`.

I have a Spock specification that likes to check the invocations of such a generated getter:

```
def "some spock test"() {
    given: def fooMock = Mock(Foo)
    when:  someFunction(fooMock)
    then:  1 * fooMock.getBar()
}
```

`someFunction()` does `fooMock.bar` but I always get

```
Too few invocations for:
1 * fooMock.getBar()   (0 invocations)
```

`1 * fooMock.bar` doesn't work, either. How can I check that `bar` is read from `Foo` in the test? It works, if I omit `final`, but this is a crappy solution...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For a `final` property, Groovy generates a `final` getter method. However, test doubles created with `Mock()`, `Stub()`, or `Spy()` are purely proxy-based, and therefore cannot intercept final methods.

Since your code under test is written in Groovy, you can use a `GroovyMock()` instead, which solves the problem.

PS: Both `1 * foo.getBar()` and `1 * foo.bar` are valid notations.

PPS: Only prefer `GroovyMock()` over `Mock()` if you have a concrete reason (mocking a final method, mocking a dynamic method, etc.). For details, see the [reference documentation](http://docs.spockframework.org/en/latest/interaction_based_testing.html#groovy-mocks-new-in-0-7).